# blowing up projetive 3-space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know that blowing up the projective plane at six distinct points gives a smooth cubic surface, and blowing up a smooth quadric surface at point gives $\mathbf{P^1 \times P^1}$.  Question:  Is there a concrete description of the blowup of $\mathbf{P^3}$ at two distinct points?

Comment: It is not true that a blowup of a quadric surface gives $\mathbf{P}^1 \times \mathbf{P}^1$, in fact a smooth quadric surface is isomorphic to $\mathbf{P}^1 \times \mathbf{P}^1$ without blowups.

Comment: Of course, the blowup of $\mathbf{P}^3$ at two points is a concrete variety, and it has many different descriptions. For instance, it is a toric variety with an explicit fan.

Comment: @W Sao. By the way, the standard Sarkisov link related $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \ldots \mathbb{P}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}^n$ is called the permutohedral variety. It is the toric variety whose associated polytope is a permutahedron. It has very easy to describe birational morphisms to $\mathbb{P}^n$ and  $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \ldots \mathbb{P}^1$ . See Tom Ducat's answer here  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374357/blow-up-of-projective-variety-p1-times-p1-times-p1-n-times-and-b/374359.

Comment: @Sasha Thanks for the correction about quadric surface being P^1 x P^1.   Where can I find more info/details about the description of blowup of P^3 at two points being toric?

Comment: The blowup of $\mathbb P^3$ at two points can always (after a projective transformation) be written as the blowup of $(0:0:0:1)$ and $(0:0:1:0)$. These are (among the points) invariant under the action of $(\mathbb C^*)^3$ on $\mathbb P^3$ by $(t_1,t_2,t_3)\cdot (w:x:y:z) = (w:t_1x:t_2y:t_3z)$. You still need to check that the action on tangent spaces works correctly, at which point you can descend it to the exceptional divisors to get an action on the blowup.